# Problema com HABTM no Cakephp 2.x

Tags: php, cakephp

Estou tendo problemas durante a pesquisa do meu método view, onde tenho a seguinte pesquisa:

```
public function view($id = null) {
    if (!$this->Setor->exists($id)) {
        throw new NotFoundException(__('Parâmetro inválido!'));
    }

    $options = array('conditions' => array('Setor.' . $this->Setor->primaryKey => $id));
    $this->set('setor', $this->Setor->find('first', $options));
}
```

Tenho o resultado no debug:

```
array(
(int) 0 => array(
    'Setor' => array(
        'id' => (int) 1,
        'nome' => 'Diretoria de Modernização Administrativa',
        'secretaria_id' => (int) 2
    ),
    'Secretaria' => array(
        'id' => (int) 2,
        'codigo' => '00004210',
        'nome' => 'Secretaria de Estado de Planejamento'
    ),
    'Veiculo' => array()
)
```

O problema é que nada está sendo listado em Veículo, mas sei que existe os dados relacionados. Quando efetuo a pesquisa do Veiculo, ele me retorna os Setores relacionados. Mas não o contrário.

A minha model de Setor está definida da seguinte forma:

```
public $belongsTo = array(
    'Secretaria' => array(
        'className' => 'Secretaria',
        'foreignKey' => 'secretaria_id',
        'conditions' => '',
        'fields' => '',
        'order' => ''
    ),
    'Status' => array(
        'className' => 'Status',
        'foreignKey' => 'status_id',
        'conditions' => '',
        'fields' => '',
        'order' => ''
    )
);

public $hasAndBelongsToMany = array(
    'Veiculo' => array(
        'className' => 'Veiculo',
        'joinTable' => 'setores_veiculos',
        'foreignKey' => 'setor_id',
        'associationForeignKey' => 'veiculo_id',
        'unique' => 'keepExisting',
        'conditions' => '',
        'fields' => '',
        'order' => '',
        'limit' => '',
        'offset' => '',
        'finderQuery' => '',
    )
);
```

A model de Veículo:

```
public $belongsTo = array(
    'TipoVeiculo' => array(
        'className' => 'TipoVeiculo',
        'foreignKey' => 'tipo_veiculo_id',
        'conditions' => '',
        'fields' => '',
        'order' => ''
    ),
    'Status' => array(
        'className' => 'Status',
        'foreignKey' => 'status_id',
        'conditions' => '',
        'fields' => '',
        'order' => ''
    )
);

public $hasMany = array(
    'Device' => array(
        'className' => 'Device',
        'foreignKey' => 'veiculo_id',
        'dependent' => false,
        'conditions' => '',
        'fields' => '',
        'order' => '',
        'limit' => '',
        'offset' => '',
        'exclusive' => '',
        'finderQuery' => '',
        'counterQuery' => ''
    )
);

public $hasAndBelongsToMany = array(
    'Setor' => array(
        'className' => 'Setor',
        'joinTable' => 'setores_veiculos',
        'foreignKey' => 'veiculo_id',
        'associationForeignKey' => 'setor_id',
        'unique' => 'keepExisting',
        'conditions' => '',
        'fields' => '',
        'order' => '',
        'limit' => '',
        'offset' => '',
        'finderQuery' => '',
    ),
    'Condutor' => array(
        'className' => 'Condutor',
        'joinTable' => 'condutores_veiculos',
        'foreignKey' => 'veiculo_id',
        'associationForeignKey' => 'condutor_id',
        'unique' => 'keepExisting',
        'conditions' => '',
        'fields' => '',
        'order' => '',
        'limit' => '',
        'offset' => '',
        'finderQuery' => '',
    )
);
```

Mesmo usando o Contain, não é retornado as relações com os Veículos.

Alguma sugestão?

Comment: Você certificou de que a propriedade `recursive` do model `Setor` está com valor 1?

Comment: Sim, já alterei o valor para 1, mas mesmo assim os veículos não são listados.  Pode ser um problema de convenção? Ou na tradução da model para o português?

Comment: Para isso, seu arquivo `bootstrap.php` precisa ser configurado por causa da mudança de singular para plural de nomes como setor, condutor e etc. Veja aqui: http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/configuration.html#inflection-configuration

Answer (score 1):

Tente adicionar na linha acima do `find` este trecho de código:

```
$this->Setor->bindModel( array('hasMany' => array('Veiculo') ) );
```

Answer (score 0):

Lá no seu controller eu vi você usar isso:

```
$options = array('conditions' => array('Setor.' . $this->Setor->primaryKey => $id));
```

Chame apenas assim:

```
$options = array('conditions' => array('Setor.veiculo_id' => $id));
```

Ou seja lá qual for o campo, mas você está chamando o índice do array como argumento de condição no find.

Prefira usar array('Model.campo' => 'Valor');

Comment: Olá, obrigado pela resposta. Mesmo assim não funcionou. Eu gostaria de obter os veículos relacionados no momento em que eu estou visualizando os dados dos setores. O estranho é que quando eu faço a mesma coisa pelo Veículo, os setores são retornados. O código está seguindo a mesma lógica. Isso realmente é um problema pra mim. Att.